# Array.includes always false javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongoose

I have the following object

```
{ _id: 58ae39c54473f9cfd4eb29b6,
  email: 'another@club.com',
  name: 'Another Club Renamed',
  __v: 0,
  createdEvents: [],
  instructors: [ 58a5ac4f84230a2117d1d6cb, 111111111111111111111111 ],
  members: [] }
```

when I use the method

`object.instructors.includes(58a5ac4f84230a2117d1d6cb)`
`object.instructors.includes(111111111111111111111111)`

or

`object.instructors.includes('58a5ac4f84230a2117d1d6cb')`
`object.instructors.includes("111111111111111111111111")`

the result is always false am I doing something incorrect?

`Array.isArray(club.instructors)` returns true

EDIT: The object is a `mongoose.document`. The object above is exactly how it gets logged to the console when I execute

```
Club.findById(id (err, club) =>{
    console.log(club);
})
```

Comment: The code as posted is syntactically incorrect; `58a5ac4f84230a2117d1d6cb` is not a valid number.

Comment: `var x = [58a5ac4f84230a2117d1d6cb, 111111]` which results in a syntax error ► `var x = [2222,1111]` is valid and so is ► `var x = ['58a5ac4f84230a2117d1d6cb',111111111111111111111111]`

Comment: What data type is 58a5ac4f84230a2117d1d6cb?

Comment: it is mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId. That is how it is when I log it to console from a mongoose query.

Comment: On a second note, how did you not notice a `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` at any stage?

Comment: Nope that object is a document returned by the mongoose library. I didn't edit it or try to assign anything to it. Just printed it to the console

Answer (score 7):

the mongo _id is 12-byte BSON type ObjectId,

So normal `object.instructors.includes('58a5ac4f84230a2117d1d6cb')` means you are comparing a raw string to an ObjectId,which is not a valid integer or string, which will always return FALSE.

*NOTE: **Tips for further understanding***

---

use lodash to check the same ObjectId stored in multiple collections

`npm i lodash --save`

in your `file.js`

`const _ = require('lodash');`

lodash `_.isEqual` performs a deep comparison between two values to determine if they are equivalent

use lodash and perform `_.isEqual` for deep comparing

```
_.isEqual(object._id, '58ae39c54473f9cfd4eb29b6') // false
_.isEqual(object.instructor[0], '58a5ac4f84230a2117d1d6cb') // false
```

suppose the `id` `58ae39c54473f9cfd4eb29b6` comes from two different mongodb documents

collection USERS: `[{_id: 58ae39c54473f9cfd4eb29b6, name: 'user1' }]`
suppose this user is referenced to `rooms` collection:

collection ROOMS: `[{_id: ObjectId, name: 'room1', userId: 58ae39c54473f9cfd4eb29b6}]`

if you do a normal comparison`===` or `includes` like this

```
if (user[0]._id === rooms[0].userId) // false due to different instances

_.isEqual(user[0]._id, rooms[0].userId) // true performs deep comparison
```

Comment: Your answer was closest to my actual solution. By lodash are you referring to a library? Or is this an inherent js feature?

Comment: lodash is a library do `npm i lodash --save`, i ran onto something similar like yours, was doing like `(object._id === 'some object ID')` returns always false, even `object._id` and compared `id` were same cause due to the instance of another object some `oops` concepts, whatever, lodash `isEqual` compares deeply, which returns `true`

Answer (score 5):

As [Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy) pointed out (hehe), the value you're using on the array, `58a5ac4f84230a2117d1d6cb`, is not a valid number. It's possible your object is not being defined properly due to that invalidity, and thus everything will return `false`, because nothing is defined.

I've tested on 
`object.instructors.includes(111111111111111111111111)`, and it works. I believe your problem is on `58a5ac4f84230a2117d1d6cb`, which if you really want to keep, should be enclosed in quotes to become a string.

Comment: The object is a mongoose.document. The object above is exactly how it gets logged to the console. I didn't create it a library did I am merely referring to it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using **includes** in js loops take care there's a *tricky note* here between **for...in** loops and **traditional loops**. check snippet ;)

A **for...in loop** only iterates over enumerable properties. Objects created from built–in constructors like Array and Object have inherited non–enumerable properties from **Object.prototype and String.prototype, such as String's indexOf() method or Object's toString() method.**

The loop will iterate over all enumerable properties of the object itself and those the object inherits from its constructor's prototype (properties closer to the object in the prototype chain override prototypes' properties).

Reference: [Mozilla Web docs for javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

console.log('** using for..in loops i actually is String')

for (var i in array)
    console.log(array.includes(i))
    
console.log('** using traditional for loops i is integer')

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    console.log(array.includes(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a search operator, according to first result of the search you can try this...

```
let { ...x} = Array1;

console.log(Array2.map((a) => a.field).includes(x[0].field))
```